# Javascript - Trying to do a foreach inside a constructur

Tags: javascript

So.. I am trying to do something which I would say is stupid simple but I really can not figure out how the hell to do this..

I made an array:

```
let configurable = [
    "raid",
    "weapon sold",
    "workbench sold",
    "smalloil",
    "largeoil",
    "roof",
    "north",
    "south",
    "east",
    "west",
    "north-east",
    "north-west",
    "south-east",
    "south-west",
];
```

And this array I want to loop through and then in the `.addFields()` add all of them.
The structure within the `.addFields()` are supposed to look like this:

```
{name: 'header', value: 'value'},
{name: 'header', value: 'value'}
```

The code I have now is this, and it does not work, and I feel like I have tried alot but there is SOMETHING I am missing to understand

```
const config = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setTitle('I am here to help you out!')
    .setDescription('The following commands are available')
    .addFields(
        configurable.forEach(element => {
            "{name = '" + "config" + "'," + "value = " + "' " + element + "'},"
        })
    )
console.log(config)
msg.channel.send(config);
```

Error I am getting is undefined and only 1 row

```
MessageEmbed {
  type: 'rich',
  title: 'I am here to help you out!',
  description: 'The following commands are available',
  url: null,
  color: 16711680,
  timestamp: null,
  fields: [ { name: 'undefined', value: 'undefined', inline: false } ],
  thumbnail: null,
  image: null,
  video: null,
  author: null,
  provider: null,
  footer: null,
  files: []
}
```

I appreciate any help there can be given here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` in this code:

```
configurable.forEach(element => {
    "{name = '" + "config" + "'," + "value = " + "' " + element + "'},"
})
```

isn't going to return anything, instead you should use `map` and then join the strings

```
configurable.map(
  element => "{name = '" + "config" + "'," + "value = " + "' " + element + "'},"
)
```

However from the [documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor) you are doing it wrong, instead you should do:

```
configurable.map(
  element => ({name :'config',value: element})
)
```

Comment: I did not know about the .map one which is way smater and does exactly what i want it to do...

Answer (score 1):

`configurable.forEach()` doesn't return anything, use `configurable.map()` instead

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, it seems you need to return an array of objects, but your current code returns a string containing a stringified object. Try this instead:

```js
configurable.map(
  element => {name: 'config', value: element};
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions!

I figured that I am just dumb and not thinking straight...

The solution I came up with:

```
const config = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#FF0000')
    .setTitle('I am here to help you out!')
    .setDescription('The following commands are available')
configurable.forEach(element => {
    config.addFields({
        name: 'config',
        value: element
    })
})
console.log(config)
msg.channel.send(config);
```

Comment: your code will work, but why use `.addFields` if you add a single element at a time? there is a `.addField` for adding a single element

Comment: also, the answers are correct, you can use `.addFields` and add multiple fields at once if you just `.map` your original array, this will return a new array of objects which all will be added then